# Deleting file in codeigniter 3.1.4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1.4.I am trying to delete a file in a folder in root directory.When i use unlink function as

```
$path=base_url()."files/image.jpg";
   unlink($path);
```

I got following Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: unlink(): http does not allow unlinking

Filename: controllers/Deletion.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\deletiontesting\application\controllers\Deletion.php
Line: 12
Function: unlink

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\deletiontesting\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

When I use file helper for this purpose as

```
$this->load->helper('file');
        $path=base_url()."files/image.jpg";
        delete_files($path);
```

The file is not deleted.file name is image.jpg folder name is files
.Please help me to delete that file

Answer (score 2):

Use FCPATH

```
$path = FCPATH  . "/files/image.jpg";

unlink($path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello don't use the base_url when you are giving path to unlink wihtout base_url give path

```
$path="../files/image.jpg";
unlink($path);
```

This always works for me, it must be work for your code to.

if `unlink($path);` gives error then try `@unlink($path);`

i hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

`'Message: unlink(): http does not allow unlinking'`

Use `__DIR__` to get to the file and then unlink it as you are doing it using http in the path and it doesn't allow to delete files like that.

Answer (score 1):

If your codeigniter is in the server root you can use:

```
 $path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/"."files/image.jpg";
```

If you have it in a subfolder:

```
$path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/subfolder_name/"."files/image.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your files folder is exist in Application folder then use APPPATH like this:

```
$path = APPPATH . '/files/image.jpg'; //to set file path
unlink($path);
```